# how does visible two models value in one view and update two models value by one controller

Tags: php, css, database, cakephp, toggleswitch

I have two Models `Group_ones` and `Group_twos`. I show this value in `ac_config.ctp` file.

My controller code is below

```
public function ac_config($id = null)
    {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Please provide a Site id');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'dashboard'));
        }

        $site_id_1          = $this->GroupOne->findById($id);
        $site_name          = $site_id_1['GroupOne']['site_name'];
        $ac_one_time        = $site_id_1['GroupOne']['ac_on_time_one'];
        $group_one_active   = $site_id_1['GroupOne']['active'];

        $site_id_2          = $this->GroupTwo->findById($id);
        $ac_two_time        = $site_id_2['GroupTwo']['ac_on_time_two']; 
        $group_two_active   = $site_id_2['GroupTwo']['active'];


        if (!$site_id_1) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Site ID Provided');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'dashboard'));
        }

        if (!$site_id_2) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Site ID Provided');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'dashboard'));
        }

        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            $this->GroupOne->id = $id;
            $this->GroupTwo->id = $id;

            if (($this->GroupTwo->save($this->request->data)) || ($this->GroupOne->save($this->request->data))) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('AC Configuration has been update'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'ac_config', $id));
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to AC Configuration has been update.'));
            }
        }

        $this->set(compact('site_name','ac_one_time','group_one_active'));
        $this->set(compact('ac_two_time','group_two_active'));

        $this->set('group_one', $site_id_1);
        $this->set('group_two', $site_id_2);

        if (!$this->request->data) {
            $this->request->data = $site_id_1;
            $this->request->data = $site_id_2;  
        }
    }
```

My view content is below
[image: Image_one]

Problem occurs when I `save` button. It only save group-2 form values in database. When `AC Run Time` and `AC Rest Time` show `Group-2` then form values save in database of the `Model Group_twos` and `AC Run Time` and `AC Rest Time` show `Group-1` then form values save in database of the `Model Group_ones`.

Another problem is below

```
if (!$this->request->data) {
    $this->request->data = $site_id_1;
    $this->request->data = $site_id_2;  // this show rest time, run time
}
```

If I write this above code then I get

[image: Image_two]

```
if (!$this->request->data) {
    $this->request->data = $site_id_2;
    $this->request->data = $site_id_1;  //this show rest time, run time.
}
```

Again if I write this above code then I get

[image: Image_three]

But I need `AC Run Time and AC Rest Time` both group same time and when I click save button any two group that corresponds group value save in Model. Whats my wrong my logic.

Thanks your help.

Comment: Turn `$this->request->data` into an array, which can hold both, currently your just overwriting it.

Comment: I am not clear your comment. Please explain more

Comment: In your code you're doing `$this->request->data = $site_id_1; $this->request->data = $site_id_2;` which will overwrite the first with the second. if it were `$this->request->data['site_1'] = $site_id_1; $this->request->data['site_2'] = $site_id_2;` you could then loop it into the right model.

Comment: would you suggest me like this 'if (!$this->request->data) {$this->request->data[0] = $site_id_1;$this->request->data[1] = $site_id_2;}'

Comment: you must use array of data => $this->request->data['site_1'] = $site_id_1; $this->request->data['site_2'] = $site_id_2;

Comment: It's pretty sound. But what portion change of my code, explain  please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply merge the two arrays before setting the request data:

`if (!$this->request->data) {
    $this->request->data = array_merge($site_id_1, $site_id_2);
}`

If this does not help, it would be useful to see the code of your view as well.

Comment: Your solution is partially correct for my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

As per your code, you are overwriting the request data array. what you need to do is that you have to set both arrays separately or by merging in the single array.

**Below your current code overwriting `$site_id_1` by `$site_id_2`:**

```
 $this->request->data = $site_id_1;
 $this->request->data = $site_id_2;
```

**Now you can pass data below ways:**

```
$this->request->data['site_id_1'] = $site_id_1;
$this->request->data['site_id_2'] = $site_id_2;
```

**or**

```
$this->request->data = array_merge($site_id_1, $site_id_2);
```

You just have to change those two lines.

Also, I don't know how you fetching the result in view for both models but you can fetch data separately something like below:

```
$site_id_1 = $this->request->getData('site_id_1');
$site_id_2 = $this->request->getData('site_id_2');
```